# Importing textures from sketchfab

Tags: import

ok so i have this model i downloaded from sketchfab and when importing it into blender when i check the rendered view the materials are blank and the downloaded zip came along with image textures (png). How do i attach them to my model?

Comment: you need to open a Shader Editor window and plug the Image Texture into the good inputs

Comment: yes i tried doing that but the output ends up being scuffed

Comment: please show the node setup, maybe share the file with its images if its copyright free: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: How did you import the file, that is which Sketchfab format did you import from?  Most sketchfab files are in either obj or gltf format and usually import with all of the textures properly set up.